# How to ADD consecutive values in a Lookup Table

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Here is an example:

I have a table, and I need to add (SUM) several consecutive numbers from this table, taking into consideration the starting index and the amount of numbers to add:

> Start Index:   4
> Number of Cells:    3
> RESULT: 345

```
        INDEX   VALUE
        1   500
        2   300
        3   190
        4   135
        5   110
        6   100
        7   90
        8   85
        9   80
        10  75
        11  70
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can almost literally translate your description into an Excel formula. Let's say column B has the numbers and the Index numbers are identical to the row numbers.

```
=sum(Index(B:B,4):Index(B:B,4+3-1))
```

If the numbers for start of index and number of cells are in worksheet cells, you can use the references to the cells

```
=sum(Index(B:B,x1):Index(B:B,x1+x2-1))
```

If Index and row numbers are not identical, you can look up the row number like this

```
=sum(Index(B:B,Match(x1,A:A,0)):Index(B:B,Match(x1,A:A,0)+x2-1))
```

[image]

Comment: If that resolved your issue, please mark the answer as described in the [tour]. If it didn't, please leave a comment, so I can follow up.

Answer (score 1):

Use `SUMPRODUCT`:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A2:A12>=E1)*(A2:A12<(E1+E2))*B2:B12)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just another approach with <kbd>Excel365</kbd> dynamic formula.

```
=SUM(INDEX(B2:B12,SEQUENCE(E4,,E3,1)))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just use `Sum` + `Offset` function

In `E3`, enter :

```
=SUM(OFFSET(B1,E1,,E2))
```

[image]

Comment: Offset() is volatile and should be avoided.